# kivymd MDTopAppBar kivymd MDTopAppBar crush android app

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

kivymd MDTopAppBar crush android app after buildozer android debug deploy run, Note that the kivymd application works without MDTopAppBar

I tried as the following and deploy to android, it works,

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
orientation: "vertical"
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"

'''

class Test(MDApp):
def build(self):
return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

But when uase MDTopAppBar the app crush on android

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"
        elevation: 10

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your buildozer requirements like this

```
requirements = python3,kivy==master,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/refs/heads/master.zip,pillow
```

This will solve your error

Answer (score 0):

**First of all it will be good if you have proided your buildozer spec file**

Well I think the error is in the spec file where you specify the requirements
try adding `requirements = python3, kivy==2.1.0, kivymd==1.1.1` instead of kivy alone as the ***MDTopAppBar is in kivy==2.1.0 version***

and modify the code a little bit for the test only

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "MDTopAppBar"

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

**also try to get logs using adb or from the directory of the path.**

Answer (score -1):

I used all the requirements as shown below and tried to troubleshoot, also used old versions of kivymd as 0.104.1, 0.104.2, the app worked and deployed in android except MDTopAppBar or MDToolbar crushes app, add to that uninstalled bulldozer and install again, I am using Ubuntu 21.10

```
                 # (list) Application requirements`enter code here`
                 # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
                 # requirements = kivy,kivymd,pillow
                 # requirements = kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow
                 # requirements = kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.0,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow
                 # requirements = kivy==2.1.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
                 # requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow
                 # requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==0.104.1,pillow
                 # requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc3,kivymd==0.104.2,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,requests
                 # requirements=python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1
```